# JavaFX chart variable scope

Tags: java, javafx, charts, javafx-8

```
final CategoryAxis yAxis = new CategoryAxis();
final NumberAxis zAxis = new NumberAxis(); 

if (cbTypeGraphView.equals("Bar Chart")) {
    BarChart<String, Number> chart = new BarChart<String, Number>(yAxis,xAxis);
}
if (cbTypeGraphView.equals("Line Chart")) {
    LineChart<String, Number> chart = new LineChart<String, Number>(yAxis,xAxis);
}

AnchorPane.setTopAnchor(chart, 110d);
AnchorPane.setLeftAnchor(chart, 10d);
AnchorPane.setRightAnchor(chart, 5d);
AnchorPane.setBottomAnchor(chart, 50d);
```

The `chart` variable looses scope outside the if statement I was wondering how this can be fixed so that the `chart` does not lose scope outside the if statement. I was thinking about using it's parent class `XYChart` class. I'm not sure how to add a `BarChart` or a `LineChart` to `XYChart`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do

```
final CategoryAxis yAxis = new CategoryAxis();
final NumberAxis zAxis = new NumberAxis(); 

XYChart<String, Number> chart = null ;

if (cbTypeGraphView.equals("Bar Chart")) {
    chart = new BarChart<String, Number>(yAxis,xAxis);
}
if (cbTypeGraphView.equals("Line Chart")) {
    chart = new LineChart<String, Number>(yAxis,xAxis);
}

AnchorPane.setTopAnchor(chart, 110d);
AnchorPane.setLeftAnchor(chart, 10d);
AnchorPane.setRightAnchor(chart, 5d);
AnchorPane.setBottomAnchor(chart, 50d);
```

You should probably deal with the case where neither `if` statement executes, in order to avoid null pointer exceptions.